# Checking for null HttpContext.Current.Cache value

Tags: c#, .net, httpcontext.cache

In the below snippet, I am trying to assign the cache value if the cache value does not already exist. I get an *Object_reference_not_set_to_an_instance_of_an_object* error when running the following. What am I missing?

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(HttpContext.Current.Cache[Key].ToString()))
                HttpContext.Current.Cache[Key] = data;
```

I looked around on SO but couldnt find something similar. Maybe I am just not wording my problem correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HttpContext.Current could be null.
HttpContext.Current.Cache[Key] could be null.

If either of those are null, it would result in the error you are getting.

Answer (score 2):

You should check for null on `HttpContext.Current` and on `HttpContext.Current.Cache[Key]`, both of which could be null. Here's a possible solution, as long as you're okay with not setting the cache key if `HttpContext.Current` is null.

```
if (HttpContext.Current != null &&
    (HttpContext.Current.Cache[Key] == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(HttpContext.Current.Cache[Key].ToString()))
{
     HttpContext.Current.Cache[Key] = data;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the NullReferenceException because you are trying to call `ToString()` on a `null` instance.

You have to check if `HttpContext.Current.Cache[Key]` is `null` before calling `ToString()`

```
if (HttpContext.Current.Cache[Key] == null)
{
   HttpContext.Current.Cache[Key] = data;
}
```

Comment: You are right, that was the issue. I just got caught up in doing things one way...

Answer (score 0):

I just changed the 'get value, convert to string, compare' logic to just get the value and see if it's null right up front. Silly me.

```
if (HttpContext.Current.Cache[Key] == null)
       HttpContext.Current.Cache[Key] = data;
```

The "*Object_reference_not_set_to_an_instance_of_an_object* error" is actually essentially the 'null' value I was looking for...

Answer (score 0):

If they key isn't present, then this would return `null`:

```
HttpContext.Current.Cache[Key]
```

You're then blindly calling `ToString()` on the value from the cache, causing the exception.

You need to assign the value from the cache to a temporary variable and test it for `null` before calling `ToString()`.